# Making a dotted grid with CSS

Tags: css, background-image, radial-gradients

I want the whole `body` to have a dotted grid

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

The problem is that I want to shift it so that a dot is placed at the point (0, 0), i.e. the top left corner of the `body`. So the whole structure should be shifted at `-20px, -20px`. Or probably there is a better solution?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Update

The following solution works, but only for a fixed `background-size`. See [@Temani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55364821/4362829) for a better solution.

#### Answer

You can use the `background-position` CSS property to do exactly what you were thinking.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -19px -19px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!! Strangely, I tried it, putting it above the whole code and it didn't work.

Comment: In your case, you are utilizing the [`background` shorthand property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) which you could supply a host of parameters. If you put the `background-position` property (or any other specific property for the background) before the `background` shorthand property, then it will be overridden by the shorthand property filling in default values. It is important that anywhere you use a shorthand property to set it first, then set any specific properties. Other examples of shorthand properties include `animation`, `flex`, `transition`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Indeed, I've forgotten about the shorthandedness of `background`.

Comment: Unfortunately the `radial-gradient` approach results in circles drawn without antialiasing. One alternative would be using a Houdini worklet to customize the painting process and draw them as shown in https://codepen.io/arnellebalane/pen/yLVOOgW however, as of early 2023, Houdini is only supported in Chromium-based browsers (not Firefox or Safari).

Answer (score 16):

Here is another way in addition to changing the `background-position` that may work whataver the size is:

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, black 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, black 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 50px 30px;
}
```

Basically the idea is to change the position of the dots inside the area defined by `background-size` to the top/left instead of shifting all the background

Comment: Very nice! Could you please explain do `at 2px 2px` and `1px` mean?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky the `1px` is basically the radius of the circle (since we are using radial-gradient) so I should place the center of the circle at `2px 2px`, it could also be `1px 1px`, should give the same result .. here is an example with bigger value to better see : https://jsfiddle.net/ (radius 10px and we place the center at 10px 10px)

Comment: @EugeneBarsky edited the answer to avoid confusion so we place it at `1px 1px` which is the radius ... and of course you can place it where you want (initially I made it 2px 2px to make it a bit far from the edge)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! Unfortunately the link to jsfiddle doesn't work.